# Firefox 'visibility' property bug?

Tags: firefox, visibility

I have some divs (class="boxes") with some text in them in paragraph tags. What I'd like is for the text to be invisible unless hovered.

However, things are behaving strangely. When I use:
.boxes p{visibility:hidden;}
.boxes p:hover{visibility:visible;} 
the text is hidden but does not become visible upon hover.

When I tried:
.boxes p{visibility:visible;}
.boxes p:hover{visibility:hidden;}
the text will (after a moment) disappear, but 'flashes' if the cursor is moved at all.

Any idea what's going on here? Firefox often updates automatically, so I believe I am running the latest version.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your HTML and try to replicate the problem on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: yup - does just the same thing there! ... now what...?
I'm sort of a noob. If there's something else you had in mind for me to do, I might have missed it.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the link to the fiddle here?

Comment: sure: http://jsfiddle.net/nX5R4/

Comment: incidentally, the same issue I described above with text also happens in the same way with images

Answer (score 0):

By making the boxes invisible, the selector stops matching them, which makes them visible, which then makes your original selector match them again and you get your flicker from an endless loop.

If you want to have your boxes still be hoverable, either give them another parent element and hide them:

```
.boxes .parent:hover p {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or give the boxes zero opacity on hover:

```
.boxes p:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I will experiment with this and get back to you. 
can you recommend a source to explain 'matching', such as it applies here? That is a new concept for me.

Comment: The opacity solution seems to work, though I am still working on comprehending the problem you describe. This column seems speak to the issue - something about the loss of functionality while using the visibility property: http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/css-difference-between-opacity0-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone.html ... any more thoughts?